# Paypal One fixed Shiping fee with mutiple items

Tags: html, paypal

I'm in the process of integrating a site with PayPal, I have added the HTML code *(see example below)* for each of the products. The only problem is if a customer adds one or more different items to their basket they are charge double the shipping, for example if I got item A the p&p is £4.95 if I then get another item lets say item B the shipping is now £9.90... I'm going to be sending all orders via one package so is there a way to setup my shopping cart so the shipping is just a total of £4.95 no matter how many items the customer has added to their basket?

```
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?business=luorders@outlook.com&cmd=_cart&add=1&shopping_url=http://www.lockersunleashed.com&currency_code=GBP&amount=7.50&item_name=Orange%20Carpet%20SKU%20LU%20C3&shipping=4.95&shipping2=1.00&country=GB
```

Answer (score 0):

If instead of setting a shipping price for each item you let it calculate to paypal?
I know you can set it in your business account

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/admin/checkout-settings/#calculating-shipping-charges-automatically